# Bartender Print Portal label query prompt not showing data

Tags: sql, printing, label, bartender

This is in regards to the BarTender labeling software and custom SQL queries to bring in data specifically to be used from the library print portal web UI for end users.  I have designed a label and am accessing data from an MSSQL data source and I used a custom sql query to read the information.  I have designed the labels text and barcode fields and it works great.  I even created a query prompt to be a placeholder in a where clause so the user could enter in some text to search for the proper object.  It all works like a charm inside the designer.  Trouble is when entering the text into the query prompt from the print portal it displays no data.  I start by going to the web print portal, select the desired label template, click print preview and the prompt opens. I enter text and then it shows nothing.  I looked every where for some kind of setup or permission thing I may need to configure but I have found nothing.  Any ideas?

This is the print portal after I enter the text.
[image]

This is the designer after I enter the same text.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I did ultimately figure this out.  The issue I finally found technically was a permissions problem in the sense that the database configuration in bartender for the label designer, was using windows authentication.  I have a sql user I setup for this but it turns out it was never using it.  I think I have stumbled upon a bug(not sure), that after I create a DB set and configure it and set the authentication for it I cannot go back and change it.  Every time I would enter the sql user account and click save it would work but that is because naturally the windows account already worked, thus I was fooled into thinking it was working.  I finally discovered it was not saving my authentication change.  I had to completely remove and re-create the DB connection with the sql user and that kept the authentication and now the print portal web page works as it should.